# Animating a Carpet Rolling Out with Three.JS - any ideas?

Tags: three.js

I am beginner to medium skills,  I can create mesh with many polygons, I need to texture map it,  those i can handle, but, how to make it Roll Up and UnRoll  (I can handle the keyframe animation -   but, i just don't know what to do to make the carpet unroll or rollup.  Can be carpet or roll of paper towels,  just need to know how to do the effect?  There are tutorials how to do it with Cinema 4D or Maya - but, i want to do it on the website within the Three.js framework.   Any ideas ???
Or is there a way to export the animation data from,  say, Blender or Maya?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's search for a tutorial on youtube to create the animation in Blender or in Maya
   (e.g.:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tN_FZiTbaG0)
2. Create your animation and export your scene into collada (.dae) format
3. Use the collada loader "webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html" example file to run your animation. (Replace "pump.dae" with your just exported animation in the example file.)

Comment: Ok  sounds good, I will try it.  That is what i was wondering, if i could import animations into three js    
I looked at the cloth example, and while it is great for dangling cloth, i don't think it will do what i want (easily).

Answer (score 0):

you could also try using this as3mod port for three.js to manually "roll" a plane. http://nikos-web-development.netai.net/blog/mod3-a-javascript-port-of-as3mod-for-three-js/