# Maya animation in Three.js

Tags: animation, maya, collada

I'm trying to get my Maya animated walk cycle into `three.js`. I have exported the animation with the model into the `.dae` format, changed the path to my model in the example. My model is being loaded, but it doesn't do any animation. What could be the problem? My main goal is to create a character who walks with `WASD` as his walk cycle is being played.

Any suggestions where should I start?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using collada loader, the animation should work without any problem. I have used the collada loader to animate one of my models using three.js, and it works like charm.

[A better example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098897/animating-a-carpet-rolling-out-with-three-js-any-ideas) to take a cue on how to make it work is webgl_loader_collada_keyframe.html .

Answer (score 0):

Converting to the DAE format and then to JS is rife with problems, and it rarely works for animations. THREE.js comes with an exporter for Maya, but it only works for static models.

I have created an updated version that also supports exporting rigged and animated models. It doesn't require any intermediate steps: it just outputs straight to a .JS file. We have a pull request to integrate the updated exporter with the THREE trunk, but if you want to get the new and improved exporter immediately you can get it from this repository: https://github.com/BlackTowerEntertainment/three.js/tree/maya_animation_exporter. The exporter files are in utils/exporters/maya.

Hope this helps.